# How to convert Android java 3rd party library to kotlin?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin

Is there any way to port 3rd party Android gradle library to kotlin.

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: To use some of 3rd party java library

Comment: There is no need to convert third party java library to kotlin to use it from kotlin, you can use it just as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import 3rd party java library as module then modify it as per your requirements. You can convert one file to Kotlin or whole library it up to you.

**3rd party library import as module steps for android studio:**

1. Open your project in Android Studio
2. Download the library (using Git, or a zip archive to unzip)
3. Go to File > Import Module and import the library as a module
4. Right-click your app in project view and select "Open Module Settings"
5. Click the "Dependencies" tab and then the '+' button
6. Select "Module Dependency"
7. Select "3rd Party Library"
8. Modify the library if you want to convert it to Kotlin etc.

Comment: Amend for 2020 situation: Step 3 should be `Go to File > New > Import Module`